# How to click the "logout" link as per the html through selenium and java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Here is the code,

```
<div id="user-tools">
    Welcome
    <strong>Admin</strong>
    /
    <a href="/">View</a>
    /
    <a href="/admin/password_change>Change password</a>
    /
    </a href="/admin/logout/">Log out</a>
</div>
```

And I am trying to use this way to click the "Log out" link, but no luck.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/admin/logout/'])".click();
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: Try using `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log out")).click();`

Comment: What do you mean by *"failed"*? Why opening anchor tag is actually closing tag?

Comment: It looks like your statement is mal-formed. You are missing an ending parenthesis and the double quotes wraping the XPath need to be inside the first ending parens: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/admin/logout/']")).click();`

Comment: Please share what error you are getting, error stack flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element with text as **Log out** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- **CssSelector**:

  ```
  "div#user-tools a[href='/admin/logout/']"
  ```
- **XPath**:

  ```
  "//div[@id='user-tools']//a[@href='/admin/logout/'][contains(.,'Log out')]"
  ```